# UIactivityViewController issue in Portrait Upside down orientation

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, uiactivityviewcontroller

My iPhone application supports all 4 orientation. In my application in used UIActivityViewController for sharing functionality which present iOS default share window. But in PortraitUpsideDown orientation, if i select any options like Assign to Contact or any other share applications like Facebook, Twitter etc app orientation is inverted.

I searched details in documentation and i can't find any details about supported orientation for share window. Is it allowable to use UIActivityViewController in UpsideDown orientation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this, extend UIActivityViewController and SLComposeViewController, override - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations method

Comment: (by writing a category for mentioned classes)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in my application i have iOS default 'Assign To Contact' option which i cannot extend/customise.